# How we can shift other elements of html like div when resizing and incresing the width of neighbour div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am new on html development. I have problem with html for handling web UI . Actually I build a small html based application which is for design a form . In this form three main things, one is Elements on left side , second is properties on right side , In centre there have resizable div, I have problem with that div that div is shifting when resizing it in right side . Down side that is perfect when resizing . I share my code please see it and run it .

**What I want?** : I want when I resize to right size my properties div also shift on right when width is increasing of resizable div. Please anyone help me who have expertise in html .

```css
.element-div {
  width:300px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px grey;
  height:auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left:20px;
  background-color:#fff;
  float:left;
  padding-bottom:18px;
}

.test {
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left : 40px;
  width: 180px;
  height: auto;
  padding:15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid burlywood;
}

#drop {
  width: 700px;
  height: 650px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px grey;
}

.dropped {
  width: 180px;
  height: auto;
  padding:15px;
  border : 1px solid burlywood;
  background-color: none;
}

.button-clone {
  background-color: coral;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: crimson;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
}

.text-clone {
  border : solid 1px;
  border-color :cornflowerblue;
  height : 25px;
  width : 100%;
}

.dropdown-clone {
  height : 30px;
  width : 100%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.date {
  border : solid 1px ;
  border-color: darkgoldenrod;
  height:25px;
  width:100%;
}

.save-form {
  background-color:#B35050;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color:#861F03;
  height:40px;
  width:80px;
  float : right;
  border-radius : 5px; 
}

h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color :brown;
}

#properties-ui {
  float:right;
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-right:10px;
  min-width:180px;
  min-height:100px;
  background-color: #AFE1E6;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px grey;
}

#header-properties {
  background-color: brown;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: -33px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px grey;
}

#delete , #clear, #save{
  background-color:#FF7C7C;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color:#ff000a;
  color : #fff;
  height:40px;
  width:80px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius : 5px; 
}

#SET {
  background-color:#3D7007;
  color:#fff;
  width:45px;
  height:30px;
  margin-top:5px;
  float:right;
  border:1px solid white;
  border-radius:6px;;
}

.pre-button {
  background-color:#496EF3;
  color:#fff;
  width:55px;
  height:25px;
  float:right;
  border:1px solid white;
  border-radius:6px;;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:ivory;">

  <div style="border:7px solid cadetblue;padding:10px;border-radius:20px;">
    <div>
      <h1>FORM TEST<input type="submit" class="save-form" name="saveForm" id="saveForm" value="Submit" style="float:right;color:#fff;" onclick="formsubmit();"></h1>  

    </div>

    <div style="margin-left:50px;margin-bottom:10px;">
      <input type="button" style="background-color:#77B337;border:1px #4E9205;"id="save" name="save" value="Save"/>
      <input type="button" style="background-color:#7C9AFF;border:1px #637ED8;" id="clear" name="clear" value="Clear" onclick="clearCanvas();" />
      <input type="button" id="delete" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="delete_Element();"/>
      <label style="margin-left:15%;">Selected Table:<input type="text" name="tablename" id="tablename" class="text-clone" style="border-color:green;width:15%;margin-left:2%; " readonly /></label>
    </div>
    <div id="properties-ui">
      <div id="header-properties"><p>Properties</p></div>
      <input type="text" id="Name" style="margin-bottom:8px;padding:3px;" placeholder="Name"><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="fieldbox" style="height:15px;width:15px;" name="fieldRequired" /> 
      <label style="font-size:14px;">Field Required</label><br><br>
      <input type="text" id="Value" style="margin-bottom:8px;padding:3px;" placeholder="Value"><br>
      <input type="color" name="colorpicker" id="bg" style="margin-top:5px;width:20px;" value="#fefefe">
      <label style="font-size:14px;">Select Color</label><br><br>
      <input type="text" id="addoption" name="addoption" style="margin-bottom:8px;padding:3px;width:100px;" placeholder="Add Options">
      <input type="button" class="pre-button" name="add" id="add" value="Add" onclick="return addoptions();" /><br><br>
      <input type="text" id="deloption" name="deloption" style="margin-bottom:8px;padding:3px;width:100px;" placeholder="Del Options">
      <input type="button" class="pre-button" name="Del" id="Del" value="Del"  style="background-color:#F95050" onclick="return deloptions();" /><br><br>
      <select id="data-column" class="dropdown-clone" style="background-color:rgb(208, 110, 6);margin-bottom:15px;height:25px;color:cornsilk" name="Name"><option value="">Name</option><option value="satinder">Satinder</option></select><br>
      <input type="button" name="setproperties" id="SET" value="SET" onclick="return setProperties();"/>
    </div>



    <div class="element-div"> 
      <h3 style="margin-left:25px;margin-top:10px;color:goldenrod;">ELEMENTS</h3>
      <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;"><input type="text" class="text-clone" name="default" style="cursor:not-allowed"></div>
      <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;"><textarea class="text-clone" name="default" style="cursor:not-allowed" placeholder=" Label here..."></textarea></div>
      <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;"><input type="text"  class="date" name="date"  style="cursor:not-allowed" id="date" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;DD-MM-YEAR"></div>
      <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;"><select id="selectbox"  class="dropdown-clone"  style="cursor:not-allowed" name="1">
        <option id="SELECT" value="">SELECT</option>

        </select></div>
      <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;" ><input type="button" class="button-clone" value="Button" style="height:50px;cursor:not-allowed;" ></div>
      <label style="margin-left : 15%;">Radio Button</label>
      <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;"><input type="radio" style="width:15px; height:15px;cursor:not-allowed;" name="radiobutton" value="default"></div>
      <label style="margin-left : 15%;">Checkbox</label>
      <div class="test red square" style="cursor:move;"><input type="checkbox" style="width:15px; height:15px;cursor:not-allowed;"></div>
      <label style="margin-left : 15%;">Combobox</label>
      <div class="test red square" id="combobox" style="cursor:move;"><input type="text" name="example"  style="cursor:not-allowed" list="exampleList">
        <datalist id="exampleList">
        </datalist></div>
    </div>  


    <div id="dd"><div style="margin-left:26%;resize: both;overflow:auto;" id="drop"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Anyone here which can help me for solve above issue .

Comment: Cannot understand exactly what you want to do ;

Comment: @NeinrappeurZaki : Sir , when you run above html script you see one large center div which is resizable . when we resize it's height from mouse parent div also increase but when we resize it's width properties div not shifting and that white div is badly effected. I want when resizing div's width that is like it's height resizing means parent div also shift which is in right side (properties div) for more details please run code . please help me .

Comment: Anyone there  for help ?